# May one go on a fishing trip during Hol Hamo'ed Pesach where chametz is used as bait?

Tags: halacha, passover, chametz-leaven, bread, fish

The captain of the boat charges for the boat tour only. He lends passengers a reel and puts a piece of bread as bait. You never touch the bread, and any fish caught will eat the bread, anyway. At the end of the trip, you return the reel to the captain.

During the period that you are fishing with the borrowed reel, are you possessing any chametz since the bait is at the end of the reel? Or since the reel and bait doesn't belong to you - it's on loan, and the bait is used to catch fish and will be (most likely) gone in a minute anyway, is this activity permitted?

Comment: That's... a reely good question...

Comment: It might depend entirely on the framing. Do you own the fish you catch? If you're essentially "fishing for the captain," then you'd be operating as a shaliach and have no possession whatsoever of anything. If you're given the reels on "loan" and/or own the caught fish then you would technically take possession of the bait and would be getting benefit from the chametz even by using it to catch fish...

Answer (score 5):

This is not permitted because one of the restrictions of Pesach is that you are not allowed to derive any benefit from Chametz.  See http://www.kosherquest.org/aboutpesach.php

Comment: But fish food is not proper for humans, if it was made before pesach that you may enjoy it, not eat it.
@DanF Are you sure it is pure Chanetz, Chamets and Chamets mixture have different dinim

Comment: See http://www.halachayomit.co.il/Default.asp?HalachaID=2469, in the one-before-last part it explains it is allowed to use fish food.
P.s noticed the question, sorry

Comment: @Zeev: Although the question specifically mentions bread, not fish food.

Comment: @Zeev - I didn't know that there was a difference. Please explain, briefly what the difference is, prior to my possibly editing the question. My main concern was regarding if it is ownership considering everything may be on loan.

Comment: @Ask613 - So, you're stating that even though the reel and equipment is on loan, I am still owning chametz. There is no prohibition if I am using someone else's chametz, AFAIK.

Comment: (Self link translation) "However, there is a difference between Chametz 'mamash' such as bread and Chametz mixture. 
The former cannot remain under your possesion unless it is inedible for even dogs. The latter may reamin during Pesach as long as it is inedible for humans. Check Shulchan Aroch Siman 442 Seif 4. Moreover, you may use Chametz mixture. See also Rishonim in Beit Yosef(same siman) and Rambam (Chapter 4, Halacha 8) ". I advise reading the link.

Comment: @DanF - But it could be argued that you are benefiting from the Chametz as you presumably would like to catch the fish and the bread is benefiting you as you are using it for a purpose.  If you do not care about catching a fish and are fishing for the enjoyment of the experience, then do not use bread as bait.

Comment: @Zeev - Interesting lesson, thanks. Leads me to another question.